# For Linear Transponder satellites, do I transmit on USB or LSB?

Tags: satellites, ssb

I'm in charge of our Field Day satellite communication, and I'm going to try and do this via SSB on one of the SSB satellites. I know they invert the signal, but is the convention to transmit on USB and receive on LSB, or the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've read (no practical experience yet!), the convention is that whoever is receiving on the downlink should be working on USB.

So fist step is to identify if the satellite is inverting or not.
If it's inverting, you transmit on LSB and receive on USB. If it's not inverting, you both transmit and receive on USB.